# Slack API: how to add `users:read` scope to a bot token

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a bot token (begins with xoxb) and am trying to make a request to [https://slack.com/api/users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) which is returning a response of `{'ok': False, 'error': 'missing_scope', 'needed': 'users:read'...}`

I can't seem to find how to add this missing scope to the `provided` list of scopes my bot token has already, nor anything indicating something like "bot token cannot be used for this request".

Any advice on how to make the above request would be useful.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your assigned scopes?

Comment: @SuyashGaur they include the following: `incoming-webhook,chat:write.customize,chat:write,chat:write.public,im:write,files:write,mpim:read`

Comment: This list does not contain 'users:read' scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can add new scopes to your app from the **OAuth & Permissions** page on the developer configuration site (https://api.slack.com/apps). Make sure to re-install the app after adding new scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the permission directly to the apps manifest file in YAML or JSON format as so:

```
...other stuff 
"oauth_config": {
            "scopes": {
                "bot": [
                   ...other Permissions
                    "users:read"
                ]
            }
        },
```

You will need to reinstall to workspace after making changes